# when i hit api from app side then my laravel code return "Get method is not allowed for this route"

Tags: php, laravel, api, routes

when i hit api from app side then my laravel 5.3 code return "Get method is not allowed for this route supported methosis PUT",
but in app side this request is PUT and in my laravel side this request is also PUT.

```
**$router->put('/booking/cancel', 'BookingController@cancel');**
```

but this works on Hostinger server but not in exmyb server..

Stuck in the case please help..

Answer (score 0):

So for 5.3, you need to spoof the form method

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#form-method-spoofing

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

Comment: app developer doing request from flutter not from  laravel web.

Comment: Still the same, do you have an input with the name of `_method` and a value of `PUT` (In other words are you sending this data, input or not), also change your PUT on your app to POST

Comment: No but it is working on other server like hostinger , so what i need to do for my server